# Clicking between lines fails

Tags: bug, design, question-lists

When viewing the list of questions, I aim my mouse for more or less the middle of the area I'm trying to click.

Trouble is, when that area is a two-line question title, that middle part just happens to not be clickable. This is actually surprisingly jarring. Please fix it ;)

Comment: Aaaaaand this is why I hate `display: inline` for hyperlinks.

Comment: @BoltClock - Agree. `display: block;
margin-bottom: 0px;` will fix the issue and it still looks the same.

Comment: This behaviour can also be seen in the "Hot Meta Posts" section, but curiously not "Related" or "Hot Network Questions".

Comment: I think you should rewrite this as "Use display: block for all hyperlinks"

Comment: @Braiam I disagree. For [example](http://example.com/), that would ([citation needed](http://xkcd.com/285/)) break a lot of [things](http://example.com/).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script contains a client-side CSS fix for this bug.
In fact, the fix has been in SOUP since June (v1.30), but it seems that I somehow completely forgot to mention it here until now. :p

The CSS (loosely based on Travis J's suggestion [in the comments above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287222/clicking-between-lines-fails/313479#comment161120_287222)) injected by SOUP to fix this bug looks like this:

```css
.question-summary .answer-hyperlink,
.question-summary .question-hyperlink,
.module.community-bulletin .question-hyperlink,
.question-summary .result-link a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

The `margin-bottom` and `border-bottom` styles are there for those SE sites that (used to) render fancy dotted underlines on links by setting a one-pixel dotted border on them.  That would look silly with `display: block`, so I replace the dotted border with an invisible one, and add a negative margin to cancel out the one pixel of vertical space it takes up.  (Just removing the bottom border entirely could interact badly with `:hover` or `:active` styles, causing the links to ["jump" by one pixel](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10227/sidebar-links-wobble-when-hovered) when clicked or hovered over.)

Actually, with the SE stylesheet redesign now mostly completed, I'm not sure if that underline kluge is used on any sites any more.  If not, those border and margin styles could be removed from SOUP; but at least they're not really doing any harm.

Ps. As a convenient side effect, this fix also makes [titles consisting of nothing but combining Unicode characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271986/%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%90%D9%91%D9%91%D9%91%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E%D9%8E) clickable.

Comment: Just FYI: This fix in SOUP, specifically the `display:block`, causes disruption of the question list for Teams listings, where the link is not the only thing on the line (the question title is shown on the line below the Team icon, instead of on the same line).